# Mysql jsont_table. Передача в процедуру json

Tags: mysql

Пытаюсь создать функцию для чтения json получаемого с фронтенда.

При отправке в процедуру значения json (в примере), происходит ошибка.

процедура:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1` PROCEDURE `sp_generate_msg` (IN `json_data` JSON)  NO SQL
BEGIN

SELECT *
FROM
JSON_TABLE(   json_data  ,'$'
COLUMNS(
    message varchar(535) PATH '$.message',
    NESTED PATH '$.from[*]' COLUMNS ( msg INT PATH '$.msg', thread INT PATH '$.thread'),
    NESTED PATH '$.img[*]' COLUMNS (src varchar(255) PATH '$.src', alt varchar(255) PATH '$.alt')
    )
)
as message;
        
        END$$
```

значение которое получает процедура:

> {   from: [ { msg: 2, thread: 2 }, { msg: 1, thread: 2 } ],           message: 'feggfsdfdsf',   img: [ { src: 'fgf', alt: 'fgfg' } ] }

сообщение об ошибке:

> Ответ MySQL: #3140 - Invalid JSON text: "Missing a name for object
> member." at position 4 in value for column '.json'.

Comment: 1. Измените имя переменной, не используйте служебные слова. 2. А где полный текст сообщения об ошибке? Или мы должны его угадать?

Comment: исправил, даже стало выводить данные, но с пустыми значениями

Comment: С точки зрения MySQL это не JSON, а хрень строковая. Все элементы, кроме чисел и констант, должны быть обрамлены двойными кавычками.